# Using IXmlSerializable interface on complex object graph

Tags: .net, xml, ixmlserializable, xml-serialization

If using custom XML Serialization (`IXmlSerialiable`), on a complex object that contains properties with constituent complex objects which do ***NOT*** use custom `IXmlSerializable` interface, how do you specify, in the `IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)` method, that you want the deserializer to use the ordinary deserialization on those child properties?

NOTE: similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209218/custome-xmlserialization-for-nested-objects)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `IXmlSerializable` is a bit tedious to implement since it's pretty much an all or nothing approach given that you cannot select child types for normal XML serialization. However, if I understood you correctly you can achieve what you want by manually creating `XmlSerializer` for the types that do not implement `IXmlSerializable`.

For example, if we start with two classes, `Default` that does not implement `IXmlSerializable` and `Custom` which does implement it.

```
public class Default // Uses default XML Serialization
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class Custom : IXmlSerializable
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadToDescendant("Count");
        this.Count = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Custom");
        writer.WriteElementString("Count", this.Count.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Then we create a third class `Parent` that has a child of each of the previous instances and implements `IXmlSerializable` in a way that calls `ReadXml/WriteXml` methods for the child that supports it and create default XML serializer for the other child.

```
public class Parent : IXmlSerializable
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.Default = new Default { Count = 1 };
        this.Custom = new Custom { Count = 2 };
    }

    public Default Default { get; set; }
    public Custom Custom { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Custom");
        this.Custom = new Custom();
        this.Custom.ReadXml(reader);

        reader.ReadToFollowing("Default");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Default));
        this.Default = (Default)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        this.Custom.WriteXml(writer);

        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Default)).Serialize(writer, this.Default, ns);
    }
}
```

To make the example complete, a sample program that serializes and deserializes a `Parent` instance:

```
static void Main()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent));

    serializer.Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), new Parent());

    Console.WriteLine(sb);

    var parent = (Parent)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(sb.ToString()));

    Console.WriteLine("Parent.Custom.Count: {0}", parent.Custom.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Parent.Default.Count: {0}", parent.Default.Count);
}
```

Comment: Thx so much... I am about to try this.. but it seems on the surface to be exactly what I need..

Comment: A little note: You can use XmlSerializer both for Default and Custom objects in WriteXml()/ReadXml() methods.

Comment: When you deserialize a child object handing it the `XmlReader`, does the reader pointer end up at the right place (just at the end of the child element), or is it retarded?